# How to hide implicit grid rows?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

The snippet below uses CSS Grid to increase the number of columns for wide containers. For narrow containers (e.g. uncomment `width: 80vw` or resize the example), it adds implicit rows (only 2 are explicit in the `grid-template-rows` property). How can I maintain only 2 rows, making the grid items that "overflow" the 2-by-n grid hidden?

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 2px solid #f76707;
  background-color: #fff4e6;
  display: grid;
  /* width: 80vw; */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 200px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.wrapper > div {
  border: 2px solid #ffa94d;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ffd8a8;
  padding: 1em;
  color: #d9480f;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
  <div>Four</div>
  <div>Five</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can set height of auto generated row to `0px` using `grid-auto-rows: 0;` and hide them using `overflow-y: hidden`. Demo:

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 2px solid #f76707;
  background-color: #fff4e6;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 200px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 0; /* set height to 0 for autogenerated grid rows */
  overflow-y: hidden; /* hide grid items that overflow */
}

.wrapper > div {
  border: 2px solid #ffa94d;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ffd8a8;
  padding: 1em;
  color: #d9480f;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
  <div>Four</div>
  <div>Five</div>
  <div>Six</div>
  <div>Seven</div>
  <div>Eight</div>
  <div>Nine</div>
  <div>Ten</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you use grid-gap with this solution you will get a buggy result. The top (as much as the grid-gap value) of the hidden rows will be visible. This you can get around by using column-gap instead, and fix the "row-gap" by adding margin-bottom to the items in the grid

Comment: That's a cool solution, quite convenient in some rare use cases. Because I used some flexbox for my grid children, I had to use `overflow-y:hidden` on the children as well to prevent some more overflow

Answer (score 2):

You can't prevent implicit rows from being created ([spec reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#implicit-grids)), but you can set a height on the container and hide the overflow.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 200px);
  max-height: 110px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid #f76707;
  background-color: #fff4e6;
  
}
.wrapper > div {
  border: 2px solid #ffa94d;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ffd8a8;
  padding: 1em;
  color: #d9480f;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div>One</div>
   <div>Two</div>
   <div>Three</div>
   <div>Four</div>
   <div>Five</div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6xbknm8L/)

Comment: The grid items have different heights?

Comment: Not within a row, but yes between grids with different content.