# Hiding grid items

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am new to css grid. I am not trying to use any frameworks. I have a template where I have 3 columns in desktop browsers, but I want a particular row to only have two columns (one of them does not display) in mobile browser. Is my `display: none` in my media query the best practice or is there a better way?

```css
.hg_header {
  grid-area: header;
}

.hg_footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}

.hg_main {
  grid-area: main;
}

.hg_left {
  grid-area: altnav;
}

header {
  background-color: yellow;
}

main {
  background-color: white;
}

aside {
  background-color: gray;
}

footer {
  background-color: black;
}

.hg {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "header header header" "altnav main main" "footer footer footer";
  grid-template-columns: 150px 1fr 150px;
  grid-template-rows: 100 1fr 50px;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .hg {
    grid-template-areas: "header" "main" "footer";
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
    grid-template-rows: 100px 1fr 50px;
  }
  .hg_left {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class='hg_header'>HEADER</header>
<main class='hg_main'>MAIN</main>
<aside class='hg_left'>ASIDE</aside>
<footer class='hg_footer'>FOOTER</footer>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grid Layout is designed for sizing and positioning grid items. It's not a tool for removing elements from a layout. For that purpose, `display: none` is a clean and valid solution.

Here's a simplified version of your code:

```css
body {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-areas: "header header header" 
                          "altnav main main" 
                        "footer footer footer";
   grid-template-columns: 150px 1fr 150px;
   grid-template-rows: 100 1fr 50px;
   height: 100vh; 
 }
 
header { grid-area: header; background-color: yellow; }
main   { grid-area: main;   background-color: white;  }
aside  { grid-area: altnav; background-color: gray;   }
footer { grid-area: footer; background-color: black;  }
 
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   body {
     grid-template-areas: "header" "main" "footer";
     grid-template-columns: 100%;
     grid-template-rows: 100px 1fr 50px;
   }
   
   aside { display: none; }
 }

body   { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<header>HEADER</header>
<main>MAIN</main>
<aside>ASIDE</aside>
<footer>FOOTER</footer>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lbs0x0ze/)

Related posts:

- [hide elements not specified in grid-template-areas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48660366/3597276)
- [How to hide implicit grid rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48692455/3597276)